# Java what is the use of the equals(Object o) function

Tags: java, function, class

```
public class TVSet {
private String brand;
private double price;
public TVSet()
{
    brand = "";
    price = 0.0;
}
public String getbrand()
{
    return this.brand;
}
public double getprice()
{
    return this.price;
}
public void setbrand(String brand)
{
    if(brand!=null)
    {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("INVAILD VALUE");
    }
}
public void setprice(double price)
{
    if(price>=0)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("INVALID VALUE");
    }
}
public void TVSet(String brand, double price)
{
    if(brand!=null)
    {
        this.brand= brand;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("INVALID VALUE");
    }
    if(price>=0.0)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("INVALID VALUE");
    }
}
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        //double temp = this.getprice();
        //DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##,00");
        //String price2 = f.format(temp);
        return String.format("%s, %.2f", brand, price);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(o instanceof TVSet)
        {
        TVSet t =(TVSet)o;
        if(price == t.price && brand == t.brand)
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is my school homework and told us to write a class encapsulating the concept of a television set, assuming a television set has the following attributes:a brand(a null-able string, default to null)and a price(a non-negative decimal number, default to 0). Please follow the naming conventions to develop the class, including
-the default constructor
-a constructor that takes the brand and the price as the parameters
-the accessor methods and the mutator methods
-the toString method that returns a string composed with (1)the brand (2)a comma, and (3)the price(rounded to the 2nd decimal place)
-the equals method
-Whenever an invalid value is supplied, print a line of the error message "INVALID VALUE" to the standard output stream.
what is the use of the equals(Object o)?

Comment: The default constructor only exists when a class does not provide one. If it provides any constructor, even a no-arg one, it's not a default constructor. You did not follow the naming conventions for the method `TVSet`, nor indeed any of the non-overridden methods.

Comment: As  the name suggests, it returns `true` if two objects are considered equal.

Comment: check this out. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the `==` operator, when used on objects, will only check to see if the two objects are identical by reference.  In your case, two different TV objects with identical brands and prices will not be equal by `==`.

The point of the `equals` method is to give you a way to see if two different objects are equivalent.  In your case, this would result in a `true` result if the two TVs are the same brand and same price.  It is this, rather than `==`, that is used in many libraries to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

The `.equals()` method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references (example below). See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) article.

```
String h = "hello";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String x = input.next();
if (h.equals(x)) { //do NOT use ==; this is not used for comparing strings 
System.out.println("h equals x");
```

Comment: this example has nothing to do with your code. It is a random simple example, to help you understand the use of `.equals()`, vs. `==`